# React-Router with multiple entry point with different parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to have 2 separated parent component which will render different layouts based on `User` and `Admin`. Since both parts will have different layouts which means for example the `NavigationBar` in `User` will be different from the `Admin`. I'm stuck and am not sure how to proceed to do this.

I'm using [this](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example) boilerplate for my project.

Currently my code is something like this

```jsx
return (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
    <Route path="about" component={About}/>
    <Route path="survey" component={Survey}/>
    <Route path="widgets" component={Widgets}/>
  </Route>
);
```

However I am not able to have a separate design for my `/admin` path.

**Update**

I was able to solve my problem by wrapping the admin portion in a route and the user in another route tag. Both are then the children of my App component.

```
return (
  <Route component={App}>
    <Route path="/admin" component={Admin}>
      <IndexRoute component={Login}/>
      <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
    </Route>
    <Route component={User}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
      <Route path="*" component={NotFound} status={404} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
);
```

Comment: You'll probably have to check `path.substr(0, 6) === '/admin'` in your `<App>` component and decide whether to return `<User>` or `<Admin>`.

Comment: I assume you have an authentication process that looks up some kind of user record? If so, rather than using the path I'd have an `isAdmin` flag there and use that in the `App` component to decide what to render.

Comment: have a look at the shared root example, it solves what you are trying to do https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/1.0.x/examples/shared-root/app.js

Comment: thanks for the suggestions and examples, I've managed to solve my problem as for now. I've updated my solution in the question, hope it'll help anyone that's facing this too. However, I'm still unsure whether this is the correct way to route separated components with different children.